# How to sum values of two tables and group by date

Tags: mysql

I am building a trading system where users need to know their running account balance by date for a specific user (uid) including how much they made from trading (results table) and how much they deposited or withdrew from their accounts (adjustments table).

Here is the sqlfiddle and tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc9e4/1

```
Adjustments table:

+-------+-----+-----+--------+------------+
| adjid | aid | uid | amount |    date    |
+-------+-----+-----+--------+------------+
|     1 |   1 |   1 |     20 | 2019-08-18 |
|     2 |   1 |   1 |     50 | 2019-08-21 |
|     3 |   1 |   1 |     40 | 2019-08-21 |
|     4 |   1 |   1 |     10 | 2019-08-19 |
+-------+-----+-----+--------+------------+

Results table:

+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+------------+
| tid | uid | aid | amount | taxes |    date    |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+------------+
|   1 |   1 |   1 |    100 |     3 | 2019-08-19 |
|   2 |   1 |   1 |    -50 |     1 | 2019-08-20 |
|   3 |   1 |   1 |    100 |     2 | 2019-08-21 |
|   4 |   1 |   1 |    100 |     2 | 2019-08-21 |
+-----+-----+-----+--------+-------+------------+
```

How do I get the below results for uid (1)

```
+--------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------+
| ResultsTotal | TaxesTotal | AdjustmentsTotal | RunningBalance |    Date    |
+--------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------+
| -            | -          | 20               |             20 | 2019-08-18 |
| 100          | 3          | 10               |            133 | 2019-08-19 |
| -50          | 1          | -                |             84 | 2019-08-20 |
| 200          | 4          | 90               |            378 | 2019-08-21 |
+--------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------+
```

Where RunningBalance is the current account balance for the particular user (uid).

Based on @Gabriel's answer, I came up with something like, but it gives me empty balance and duplicate records

```
SELECT SUM(ResultsTotal), SUM(TaxesTotal), SUM(AdjustmentsTotal), @runningtotal:= @runningtotal+SUM(ResultsTotal)+SUM(TaxesTotal)+SUM(AdjustmentsTotal) as Balance, date
FROM (
  SELECT 0 AS ResultsTotal, 0 AS TaxesTotal, adjustments.amount AS AdjustmentsTotal, adjustments.date
  FROM adjustments LEFT JOIN results ON (results.uid=adjustments.uid) WHERE adjustments.uid='1'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT results.amount AS ResultsTotal, taxes AS TaxesTotal, 0 as AdjustmentsTotal, results.date
  FROM results LEFT JOIN adjustments ON (results.uid=adjustments.uid) WHERE results.uid='1'
) unionTable
GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY date
```

Comment: done. thanks @Barmar

Comment: You need to initialize `@runningtotal` to 0, or use the `IFNULL` call as in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are asking you would want to union then group the results from both tables, this should give the results you want. However, I recommend calculating the running balance outside of MySQL since this adds some complexity to our query.

Weird things could start to happen, for example, if someone already defined the @runningBalance variable as part of the queries scope.

```
SELECT aggregateTable.*, @runningBalance := ifNULL(@runningBalance, 0) + TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(ResultsTotal), SUM(TaxesTotal), SUM(AdjustmentsTotal)
   , SUM(ResultsTotal) + SUM(TaxesTotal) + SUM(AdjustmentsTotal) as TOTAL
   , date
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 AS ResultsTotal, 0 AS TaxesTotal, amount AS AdjustmentsTotal, date 
    FROM adjustments
    UNION ALL
    SELECT amount AS ResultsTotal, taxes AS TaxesTotal, 0 as AdjustmentsTotal, date
    FROM results
  ) unionTable
  GROUP BY date
) aggregateTable
```

Comment: almost. still missing the running balance.

Comment: @Thiago you haven't mentioned the schema that includes running balance.

Comment: I can not come up with a clear way from the data you have provided to calculate a running balance. For example, for '2019-08-19' you have a running balance of 133. If I add the other 3 columns it does not equal 133. However, what I have shown you is how to effectively aggregate your data between your two tables and sum the others. With my answer, I believe you can find a solution to your new question.

Comment: @GirishPandey, the running balance is the sum of all totals like a bank statement where you see all the money that goes in and out of your account.

Comment: @GabrielGates, I could do some additional computing outside mysql to come up with an answer so it is a great start. 133 is the sum of all totals up to that date, like a bank account statement where you see your running balance from all the deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: @Thiago I would recommend that, however, I did update my answer. It does introduce complexity to our query,

Comment: Thank you @GabrielGates! Works great.